# php loop for (count array)/times

Tags: php, arrays, loops, count

I have a function `geturls()` that returns `$urls` as array

```
$urls[1] $urls[2] .....$urls[44]
```

However I don't know count of `$urls` (sometimes 44 45 77 ....)

And I want to make a loop for many times (44 in this case but could change)

So here is my script

```
function geturls($xml){
//my function
}

$urls = geturls($xml);
$counti = count($urls);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $counti; $i++) {
$modifiedurl = modify($urls[$i]);
echo $modifiedurl;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this (I'm sure there is a better way without using count() )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can walk through an arrays elements with the array map function.

```
$modifiedUrls = array_map('modify', $urls);
```

Just made a test about our answers.

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);

$urls = range(1, 1000000);

function modify($url)
{
    return "modified_".$url;
}

$modified_urls = [];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $modified_urls[] = modify($url);
}

// $modified_urls = array_map('modify', $urls);

$end = microtime(true);

$time_elapsed_secs = $end - $start;

echo $time_elapsed_secs;
```

- foreach: 0.202~ ms
- array_map: 0.130~s ms

Comment: Thank you Ozan, but which is better in term of memory your way or the way of BEn Pearl Kahan ?

Comment: A foreach loop is always faster than map, but I always felt like it's a bit cleaner.

Comment: False comment! Sorry about that. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach()`:

```
$modified_urls = []; //create new array for modified URLs

foreach($urls as $url){
    $modified_urls[] = modify($url); //modify this URL and add it to the array
}

print_r($modified_urls); //output the array
```

Comment: Thank you for this fast answer

Comment: Please see answer by Ozan Kurt, which one do you think is better in term of memory ?